# Rewriting Link with mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a link being sent to users in one format, but I need to make sure it passes through a main index page for login purposes. I figured mod rewrite was the way to go.

Link being clicked on by user:

```
https://sub.domain.com/link/link.jsp?pageId=1234567&id=12345
```

Where it needs to go:

```
https://sub.domain.com/index.html?o=(full original URL from above, including query string)
```

The o= in this case will let the user login and pass them along to that original URL. Now, there are also some images and a style sheet involved, so I need to have the rewrite ignore them.

After reading documentation and a number of code examples (many from this site), I tried to just get a basic code going to see if my rewrites will even work, as I'm new to this.

This appears to force the URL to rewrite but isn't passing the user along to the original link:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://sub.domain.com/index.html?o=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Also please note this is all going inside a virtual host, not htaccess. As I said, the code above appears to redirect when I test it, but it might be unintended and not at all how I should write it.

I also tried adding in this code for images/stylesheet ignores

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|jpeg)$ [NC]
```

At that point everything went crazy, but I know it's because I'm slapping code together and thinking it's going to work. From that point I tried a lot of changes, but most resulted in a loop condition and I kept falling back to square one (original code you see above). Apologies for the long winded post, but I'm hitting my head against a wall at something I thought wouldn't be difficult. Obviously, despite reading, I'm lacking some understanding. Any guidance would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current solution is: an URL is only allowed to have one `?` inside.

Note that your code will send a redirection status code to redirect inside the browser, because you provided a FQDN. Try doing an internal redirect by just using `/index.html?o=...`. If that doesn't work either (not sure right now), URL-Encode the second `?`

[Edit]: rewrite, guess I got the question wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Before I saw this, I poked around more and managed to get this code to solve all but one issue (the ? issue). RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://sub.domain.com/index.html?o=$1 [QSA,R=301,L]